# Handling more than one markup language in a text area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown, bbcode, textile

I'd like to now how to handle multiple markup languages (textile, markdown and bbcode) in a text area using ruby on rails 3.

The user would be able to select the markup language he/she wants to use, write in that language, and then the view would render the text using the markup language selected by the user.

I'm currently handling that storing a field for each text area, but I'm sure there are better ways and I'd love to hear your opinions and come up with a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When are you processing the markup the user enters? Are they ever going to need to re-retrieve it?

I'd do this by having three attributes on my model: `original_text`, `markup_language` (which is either textile, markdown, or bbcode), and `rendered_text`. When the user hit save, I'd save the text and use the value they provided for `markup_language` to figure out what renderer to use to store it into `rendered_text`.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to need to re-retrieve the markup_language the user has selected and the original_text. I like the use of rendered_text to cache the text already rendered, I thought of rendering each time on the view. This method is much better. The problem with your solution is that I'm going to need this approach on a lot of models and fields, and making original_text, markup_language and rendered_text for each field I want to use is not very DRY. How would I approach this on a more DRY way? Maybe inserting a little model (MarkupText model) on every field that needs that? Is that possible?

Comment: It's definitely possible - you'd just need to make a foreign key for each of your `fields`, instead of having them on your model directly.

Comment: Thanks then. I'm going to use that solution :D