# Rails named has_many with a limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, polymorphic-associations

I want to achieve a has_many association with a x number of records, and the records would be named.

Let's explain that better. In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620690/handling-more-than-one-markup-language-in-a-text-area) I asked how to make a text area with a selectable markup language and we reached the conclusion that I needed a separate model, `Field` which had the multiple fields I needed (`language`, `original` and `rendered`).

Now I want to be able to make a model, let's say `User`, which had two of these fields. For example: `about_me` and `biography`. How would I create those fields every time I create the user, edit them when I edit the user and destroy them when I edit the user? And how would I display them simply writing: `User.about_me` and `User.biography`?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David's solution creates the joint model.

Then you have to include the form of the profile in the User form. You'll have to use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) method in the User model.

To destroy the profile when user is deleted, add `dependent => :destroy` to the relationship between the 2 models.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use callbacks (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

For example, in your `User` model, have a after_create callback that will create the requisite fields.

Also,have an after_save callback that checks user.changed? and if it is different, update the fields.